# Specify minimum python version with py.exe (python launcher for windows)

Tags: python, windows, launcher

I am using **py.exe** to fire a py script to require a minimal python version (3.6 in my case).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
...
...
```

This requires you to have some 3.6.x installed. How can I tell it my script also works with 3.7  and above? Is it even possible?

EDIT to make it more clear: In other words I'd like to run my script with any version above 3.6.x. I don't want to be told:

```
Requested Python version (3.6) is not installed
```

when I do have 3.7.

Comment: If 3.6 is a minimum requirement and it has not a maximum threshold means that it works with the above versions. Otherwise you can just add a comment or a requirements file in your project.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis I've edited the answer after your comment. Thanks

Comment: Shebangs don't work like that. If py.exe supported some extended feature that did what you want, your script would not be portable. All we can do is use `#!/usr/bin/python3` and fail with an error message if `sys.version_info[:2] < (3, 6)`.